# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 260, 540, 3) for Tensor 'input_image: 0', which has shape '(?, 160, 160, 3)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

iam new to tensorflow, i am geeting this value error for some images while on other images works fine. is there anything wrong with the code?

error:
**ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 260, 540, 3) for Tensor 'input_image: 0', which has shape '(?, 160, 160, 3)'**
tensorflow version==1.14
dlib version==1.19

code:

```
import argparse
import os

import cv2
import dlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from imutils.face_utils import FaceAligner
from imutils.face_utils import rect_to_bb
from numpy import array
import inception_resnet_v1

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''


def eval(aligned_images, model_path):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sess = tf.Session()
        images_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 160, 160, 3], name='input_image')
        images = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.reverse_v2(frame, [-1]), images_pl) #BGR TO RGB
        images_norm = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.image.per_image_standardization(frame), images)
        train_mode = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
        age_logits, gender_logits, _ = inception_resnet_v1.inference(images_norm, keep_probability=0.8,
                                                                     phase_train=train_mode,
                                                                     weight_decay=1e-5)
        gender = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(gender_logits), 1)
        age_ = tf.cast(tf.constant([i for i in range(0, 101)]), tf.float32)
        age = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.nn.softmax(age_logits), age_), axis=1)
        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                           tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            print("restore and continue training!")
        else:
            pass
        return sess.run([age, gender], feed_dict={images_pl: aligned_images, train_mode: False})


def load_image(image_path, shape_predictor):
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(shape_predictor)
    fa = FaceAligner(predictor, desiredFaceWidth=160)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # image = imutils.resize(image, width=256)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rects = detector(gray, 2)
    rect_nums = len(rects)
    XY, aligned_images = [], []
    if rect_nums == 0:
        aligned_images.append(image)
        return aligned_images, image, rect_nums, XY
    else:
        for i in range(rect_nums):
            aligned_image = fa.align(image, gray, rects[i])
            aligned_images.append(aligned_image)
            (x, y, w, h) = rect_to_bb(rects[i])
            image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
            XY.append((x, y))
        return np.array(aligned_images), image, rect_nums, XY


# def draw_label(image, point, ages, genders, font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, font_scale=1, thickness=1):
#     for i in range(len(point)):
#         label = "{}, {}".format(int(ages[i]), "F" if genders[i] == 0 else "M")
#         size = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, font_scale, thickness)[0]
#         x, y = point[i]
#         # cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y - size[1]), (x + size[0], y), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
#         cv2.putText(image, label, (x, np.max(y - 5, 0)), font, font_scale, (255, 255, 255), thickness)

def draw_label(image, point, ages, genders,font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
               font_scale=1, thickness=2):
    for i in range(len(point)):
        label = "{}, {}".format(int(ages[i]), "F" if genders[i] == 0 else "M")
        size = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, font_scale, thickness)[0]
        x, y = point[i]
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y - size[1]), (x + size[0], y), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(image, label, point[i], font, font_scale, (255, 255, 255), thickness)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--image_path", "--I", required=True, type=str, help="Image Path")
    parser.add_argument("--model_path", "--M", default="./models", type=str, help="Model Path")
    parser.add_argument("--shape_detector", "--S", default="shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat", type=str,
                        help="Shape Detector Path")
    parser.add_argument("--cuda", default=False, action="store_true",
                        help="Set this flag will use cuda when testing.")
    parser.add_argument("--font_scale", type=int, default=1, help="Control font size of text on picture.")
    parser.add_argument("--thickness", type=int, default=1, help="Control thickness of texton picture.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not args.cuda:
        os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''
    aligned_image, image, rect_nums, XY = load_image(args.image_path, args.shape_detector)
    ages, genders = eval(aligned_image, args.model_path)
    print(ages, genders)
    draw_label(image, XY, ages, genders, font_scale=args.font_scale, thickness=args.thickness)
    plt.imshow(image[:, :, (2, 1, 0)])
    plt.show()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you specific `shape=[None, 160, 160, 3]` in `images_pl`. This means the input images have to be 160x160 but from the error you're trying to feed the model with a 540x260 image.

So the solution is either

1. Change `None, 160, 160, 3` to `None, None, None, 3`. This will makes the model accept image with any size as long as it's 3 channels. Note that some layers need the input to be a specific size so this might not work sometime and if you train only on 160x160 the result won't be good.
2. Resize the image to 160x160.

### Edit

Just a guesswork but I suppose these lines

```
if rect_nums == 0:
        aligned_images.append(image)
        return aligned_images, image, rect_nums, XY
```

When `rect_nums == 0` (no face detected?) it will return the original image without any resize. So either change `aligned_images.append(image)` to `aligned_images.append(cv2.resize(image, (160, 160)))` but this probably doesn't work as you don't have the faces there anyway or just print something like "No face detected".

For example

> 1 Raise the error if no face

```
if rect_nums == 0:
   raise ValueError('No face detected in this image')
```

> 2 Return `None` and `imshow` the raw image

```
if rect_nums == 0:
    aligned_images.append(image)
    return None, None, None, None
```

and change here

```
if aligned_image is not None:
    ages, genders = eval(aligned_image, args.model_path)
    print(ages, genders)
    draw_label(image, XY, ages, genders, font_scale=args.font_scale, thickness=args.thickness)
```

### P.S.

Just a tip but you can change `plt.imshow(image[:, :, (2, 1, 0)])` to `plt.imshow(image[..., ::-1])` and get the same result.